# In my example, how do I use in-text citation?

Tags: citation

I'm writing an economics research paper based on my professors journal. We only use one reference, and that is my professor's journal article. I want to use a sentence which has in-text citations. I also cannot reword this sentence because it is a list. It is exactly as follows:

motor vehicle accidents (the leading cause of death and injury in this age group), homicides, suicides, falls, and other accidents are all strongly associated with alcohol consumption (Bonnie and O’Connell, 2004).

Should I put quotation marks on it? Should I cite it using his journal as the reference or do I use the same citation he uses?

Comment: You should be able to get answers from [here](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/02/).  MLA is the most commonly used formatting style in this type of writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated I stated in comments follow [MLA](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/02/) for guidance on the proper formatting.

With regard to your other questions:

Only use quotation marks for direct quotations.  Paraphrasing requires no quotation marks.

And, site the source that you are using.  If you read *his* source and wish to quote it, then that is perfectly appropriate to cite that source.  If you have only read this particular journal article, then you can only cite that.

And, you can reword that sentence:

> Alcohol consumption is strongly associated with motor vehicle accidents, homicides, suicides, falls, and other accidents.  Motor vehicle accidents are the leading cause of injury and death in this age group.

Comment: Do I use in-text citation for both sentences? or just at the end of the second sentence?

Comment: If you are citing one idea, then you just cite at the end of the complete idea.  If you are citing separate ideas from separate sections of text, then you would cite at the end of each sentence.